How can I implement Gmail API access for the login over Auth.js (with Google OAuth)?
I have a Next.js app where the user currently can sign in over Google OAuth (Auth.js is used). Now I want access to the users gmail inbox, but if I follow the Gmail API docs the user has to login again. Can I prevent this? Are there some good tutorials for this use case?


Your auth.ts file should look similar to this. Google provider should have all the configuration listed below, all the scopes you require for the application. This configuration will make Google return Refresh Token. Store that refresh token using signIn callback in your database. With this Refresh Token of the user and your Gmail API key, you will be able to access user's gmail with just one consent screen which will include login and authorization.

export default {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ account, user }) {
      if (account?.access_token && account?.refresh_token) {
        await storeRefresh(account.refresh_token, account.providerAccountId);
      }

      return true;
    }
  },
  providers: [

    Google({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          access_type: "offline",
          prompt: "consent",
          response_type: "code",
          scope:
            "openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
            },
          },
        })
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

